# How to get all granted permissions of a app

Tags: android

I want to get all granted permissions. I know I can get all requested permissions by `packageinfo.requestedPermissions` but I want to know list of granted permissions and granted permissions can be lesser then requested in case of android M. So I just wanted to know that is there way that I can get list of all granted permissions?

I know from list of requested permission I can check for that permission weather granted or not but I want to know list of all granted permission. Don't want to check for every requested permission.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is with writing a loop that iteratives over `requestedPermissions` and checks if the corresponding `requestedPermissionsFlags` element contains `REQUESTED_PERMISSION_GRANTED`. That's what the flags are for. Create a function for it if you need to do it more than once.

Comment: Thanks, There is no problem, I just wanted to is there a way to get list of all granted permissions but now i think it's not so will do what you suggested. You can write answer for this also, it's better then other answers.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A simple function that returns all the permissions that have been requested and granted for a given package could look like this:

```
List<String> getGrantedPermissions(final String appPackage) {
    List<String> granted = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        PackageInfo pi = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(appPackage, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
        for (int i = 0; i < pi.requestedPermissions.length; i++) {
            if ((pi.requestedPermissionsFlags[i] & PackageInfo.REQUESTED_PERMISSION_GRANTED) != 0) {
                granted.add(pi.requestedPermissions[i]);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return granted;
}
```

Note that this requires API level 16 or above, but that should hopefully not be an issue these days.

Comment: is there a way to get all the permission groups granted to an app?

Comment: @Michael : Could you explain what does this statement actually do (pi.requestedPermissionsFlags[i] & PackageInfo.REQUESTED_PERMISSION_GRANTED) != 0

Comment: `requestedPermissionsFlags` is an array of flags of all `<uses-permission>` tags included under `<manifest>`.
And `REQUESTED_PERMISSION_GRANTED` is a bitmask for the entries in `requestedPermissionsFlags` to check if the requested permission is currently granted to the application.

Comment: Just to be safe, the "flags" test should be `if ((pi.requestedPermissionsFlags[i] & PackageInfo.REQUESTED_PERMISSION_GRANTED) ==
                    PackageInfo.REQUESTED_PERMISSION_GRANTED)`

Comment: I don't know why but this function not returning permission of some app !

Comment: @swooby: I haven't tested but it seems your suggested condition will return true even if no permission is granted.

Answer (score 0):

I am also needed to know which permissions are granted by user and which are not for particular package. So below the function I have used to get that permission list.

Java

```
private Map<String, List<String>> getAppPermissionsList(String packageName) {
    List<String> granted = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> denied = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        PackageInfo pi = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(appPackage, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
        for (int i = 0; i < pi.requestedPermissions.length; i++) {
            if ((pi.requestedPermissionsFlags[i] & PackageInfo.REQUESTED_PERMISSION_GRANTED) != 0) {
                granted.add(pi.requestedPermissions[i]);
            }else {
                denied.add(pi.requestedPermissions[i]);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("granted", granted);
    map.put("denied", denied);
    return map;
}
```

Kotlin

```
private fun getAppPermissionsList(appPackage: String): Map<String, List<String>>? {
    val granted: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    val denied: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    try {
        val pi = packageManager.getPackageInfo(appPackage, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS)
        for (i in pi.requestedPermissions.indices) {
            if (pi.requestedPermissionsFlags[i] and PackageInfo.REQUESTED_PERMISSION_GRANTED != 0) {
                granted.add(pi.requestedPermissions[i])
            } else {
                denied.add(pi.requestedPermissions[i])
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    val map: MutableMap<String, List<String>> = HashMap()
    map["granted"] = granted
    map["denied"] = denied
    return map
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can check permission one by one and add to list:

// Should we show an explanation?

```
        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
        if((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
        {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
        if((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
        {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS);
        }
        if((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
        {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        }
        if((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
        {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
        if((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
        {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        }
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context,
                    listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_MULTIPLE_PERMISSION);
        }
```