# How can I get a list of application that are allowed installation of other apps in Android (from my app)?

Tags: android, permissions

I'm trying to get a list of applications that are allowed to install other applications (in Android O and higher).

I can see whether my app is granted or not this permission by `getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls();`

However, this works only for my app.
I want to get the list of all apps that are granted `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission.

I can get those that requested this permission, but I need those that were granted.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37294804/8728259) gives a list of granted permissions of other apps, but it does not show `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` for some reason.

Comment: Well, so far, I can't find a way to do it. Looking through the source, that value is now set and read for a given package through `AppOpsManager`, but with hidden fields and methods. Even when I try reflection, it throws a `SecurityException` because I don't have the `UPDATE_APP_OPS_STATS` permission, which normal apps can't get. Have you seen an app that can do this?

Comment: So far, I found only one app that can do it. It is settings -> Apps & notifications -> Advanced -> Special app access -> Install unknown apps. And there will be a list with all apps that are granted installation from unknown sources. I have not found any third party app that can do it.

Comment: Yeah, I meant third-party apps. Not sure that we'll be able to do this as a normal app on a standard system.