# Get all permissions during app installation

Tags: android, apk

I need to develop an android application to grant all permissions before installing app
Please let me know how to edit apk file to grant all permissions before installing

Comment: add all runtime permission into your splash/welcome screen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all granted permissions of a app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37294242/how-to-get-all-granted-permissions-of-a-app)

Comment: maybe i say my question wrong ! i need make apk file how it do grant all permissions in installing , you know after installed the apk , grant all permissions allow by it self , sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: You can not install an app that automatically has been granted all of the permissions.  You can only request permission at runtime now, and still, you cannot force the user's decision to either grant or deny the permission.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible now. From Android 6.0, applications provide transparency to users. Users have to grant permissions to applications while the application is running rather than during installation and it asks to grant the permission only when some specific function is being used within an app.

[Refer This](https://vmokshagroup.com/blog/android-runtime-permissions/)

EDIT: And you cannot grant permission before installing app even in pre 6.0 versions.

Comment: maybe i say my question wrong ! i need make apk file how it do grant all permissions in installing , you know after installed the apk , grant all permissions allow by it self , sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: @user3228899 then the first paragraph is my Answer. you cannot grant all permission in background. User himself has to grant all permission manually due to security reason.

Comment: my phone is android 9 , and some app install without my permission set ! it grant by self , how ?! example : AhMyth android rat apk builder

Comment: @user3228899 that is not a published app, and as far as I see in the code it never really asks for any permissions hence being detected as malware https://github.com/AhMyth/AhMyth-Android-RAT/issues/54

Comment: see : https://i.ibb.co/dKHB92v/Screenshot-20200212-184846.jpg ( this app wont grant automaticly ) BUT this app -->>>https://i.ibb.co/Ms1F0Lf/Screenshot-20200212-184842.jpg  grant everything with installing

Comment: @user3228899 That was how permissions were being granted before Marshmallow. You would have to accept everything upon installing the app. You can't do that on a device that runs Android >=6

Comment: @user3228899 try to install this app on or above 6.0

Comment: already installed on oneplus 6

Comment: @user3228899 is your phone rooted? Is the above screenshot with the list of permissions from your oneplus?